# Compatibility of Drools' dependency xstream and Java 11

Tags: drools, xstream, kie

We are using Drools in a Java 11 Web application via the `kie-spring` library.

This library depends on `xstream`.

The compatibility of xstream with newer Java versions is uncertain as described in [this Issue](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/101)  which is already 3 years old and not going to be "fixed" as far as I understand it.

Is there a plan to switch to a different underlying technology or any other changes that would move away from xstream? Or at least a way to get rid of the JVM warning and assurance that it will work with future versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `XStream` problem. The very link which is shared in the original question, provide some valid solutions to avoid the mentioned `XStream` issue.

> Is there [...] at least a way to
> get rid of the JVM warning and assurance that it will work with future
> versions?

As can be seen on this change https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/pull/2988#issuecomment-658079653 modifications are already underway to resolve the mentioned issue as it manifests inside the Drools project which make use of the `XStream` library.

So this is resolved currently for the Drools' DMN module, and Kogito; if you spotted a specific module of Drools which is not yet updated, you are encouraged to [raise a JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/DROOLS).

Question on StackOverflow is one of the channel we monitor as @schrobe correctly [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013058/compatibility-of-drools-dependency-xstream-and-java-11#comment111434534_63013058); if you need a more back/forth exchange you can also interact with Drools developers via [chat](https://kie.zulipchat.com/) or [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage). All these are valid channel that we monitor as originally described in the project [get help page](https://drools.org/community/getHelp.html).

I hope this fully answers your original question, let us know if you noticed the issue in other modules!